# Изменить значение переменной массива в ansible

Tags: ansible, mount, ansible-playbook, uuid

Хочу смонтировать RAID. Использую `mount`, и в документации есть пример, где монтирование происходит по UUID (https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/mount_module.html). Как определить значение переменной `uuid` и добавить ее в массив или изменить ее значение?

Есть массив элементов

```
mdadm_arrays:
  - name: 'md3'
    devices:
      - '/dev/sdc1'
      - '/dev/sdd1'
    filesystem: 'ext4'
    level: '1'
    mountpoint: '/home/2'
    state: 'present'
    opts: 'defaults'
    uuid: "N/A"
```

переменная `uuid`, не определена.

определяю `uuid`

```
 - shell: "blkid -s UUID -o value /dev/{{ item.name }}"
   register: rez
   with_items: '{{ mdadm_arrays }}'
```

Comment: Можно выхлопов добавить в вопрос? Рейда под рукой нет, сложновато вспомнить чё там вываливается.

Comment: @don_Rumata что конкретно добавить?

Comment: Ну `fdisk -l` и `blkid` хотя бы.